# what's the best way to filter passwords out of log files in a Koa app?

Tags: node.js, logging, koa2

I'm working on a NodeJS app that is using KoaJS. By default, I see all the request data in the STDOUT log, which includes user's password when they register.  I've used express middleware with options that filter out specific attributes in the past, and wondering what are good options to do this with Koa.  Here are the Koa modules I'm using

```
"koa": "^2.3.0",
"koa-better-body": "^3.0.4",
"koa-better-flash": "0.0.3",
"koa-bodyparser": "^4.2.0",
"koa-csrf": "^3.0.6",
"koa-ejs": "^4.1.0",
"koa-passport": "^4.0.1",
"koa-redis": "^3.1.1",
"koa-router": "^7.2.1",
"koa-session": "^5.5.0",
"koa-static": "^4.0.1",
```

I looked at a few logger options:

- koa-logger: http://github.com/koajs/logger “Development style logger middleware for koa.” Doesn’t seem to have any configuration options (v3.1.0)
- winston: mature logging library, https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston seems to be widely used and has nice configuration options, ideally I could use this with middleware:

  - https://github.com/selbyk/koa-logger-winston doesn’t seem to support configuration
  - https://github.com/yidinghan/koa2-winston has config for filtering & transport
- morgan: seems to be a popular request library and [one article](https://coralogix.com/log-analytics-blog/node-logging-best-practices-tips/) recommended using it with winston, might be good for concise logging of requests when running in production with Warn or Error level logs. Originally [part of express-js](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan), there’s a [koa-morgan](https://github.com/koa-modules/morgan)

Before I choose one of these options, I thought I would ask whether there's some way to configure this that is built into one of the koa modules I'm already using or is setting up a logger that supports filtering the right way to go?

Comment: The best way would be to send passwords in a way that doesn't get logged in the first place.  Why are they even getting logged at all?

Comment: Good point.  I made the incorrect assumption that the logging was coming from one of the libraries... found the spot in the app code that was doing the logging.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to this question was to look deeper at the source of the problem -- thank @jfriend00 for the tip in the comment!

Found where the password was being logged and omitted it:

```
log.info('Register user', _.omit(ctx.request.body,"password"));
```